# Is it possible to install LuCi to a chinese router with custom ui?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, putty

I have a chinese router with openwrt installed 'out of the box'. Its web ui is terrible. I couldnt find any port forwarding and had to manually add it in html code editor (it was with style display none). I wonder if it's possible to  install standart luci to it. Router is unknown brand. I'm a noob in openwrt, but I know how to connect to it using PuTTY (I determined it's openwrt that way).

Answer (score 0):

I think Luci will be already installed in it, then also you can try to do ssh or scp. Try ssh using putty and then type command

```
opkg list-installed
```

This command will show the packages installed in it. Check luci is installed or not. If not then type in putty

```
opkg update
opkg install luci
```

If its already installed then it will in Chinese version. So, try another firmware on your own risk.

Comment: Yup, it's installed, but no normal openwrt interface, can i fix it?

Comment: Okay, i found something. cpuinfo says device type is Atheros AR9330 rev 1 (probably cpu), machine Cdata Wifi v1 (google gives me something really simillar to my router), cpu model is MIPS 24Kc V7.4 (i dont know what it is), i also fully uninstalled luci* and luci-*. I still can properly use web interface, its under /cgi-bin/,

Comment: only thing changed when i go to 192.168.1.1 i have a menu that says "
../
modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:02:05 GMT
directory - 0.00 kbyte

cgi-bin/
modified: Tue, 04 Jul 2017 15:13:25 GMT
directory - 0.00 kbyte

luci-static/
modified: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 08:45:47 GMT
directory - 0.00 kbyte

www/
modified: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 13:24:29 GMT
directory - 0.05 kbyte
"

Comment: and if i go to /cgi-bin/ then i get redirected to web ui

Comment: Here are some kernel log lines


  Kernel log
[ 0.000000] Linux version 3.10.15 (tomsonx@tomsonx-vm-ubuntu) (gcc version 4.6.4 (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.6-2013.05 unknown) ) #3 Tue Jul 19 21:24:43 HKT 2016
[ 0.000000] MyLoader: sysp=ef8b8218, boardp=b1f6257d, parts=fe5f9c45
[ 0.000000] bootconsole [early0] enabled
[ 0.000000] CPU revision is: 00019374 (MIPS 24Kc)
[ 0.000000] SoC: Atheros AR9330 rev 1
[ 0.000000] Clocks: CPU:400.000MHz, DDR:400.000MHz, AHB:200.000MHz, Ref:25.000MHz

Comment: Search in google gave me this router: TP-Link TL-MR3020, it has the same cpu